# Firestore query not working and null values are returned by DocumentSnapshot

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch the below query but it is giving null result.

```
result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc('EOLjcTCCvMfsi9mnbNynAGwCo723')
          .get();
OnboardingUser user = OnboardingUser.fromFirestore(result.data(), null);
```

Here is the code to convert firestore snapshot to object

```
factory OnboardingUser.fromFirestore(
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
    SnapshotOptions? options,
  ) {
    final data = snapshot.data();
    return OnboardingUser(
      firstName: data?['firstName'],
      lastName: data?['lastName'],
      phoneNumber: data?['phoneNumber'],
      age: data?['age'],
      grade: data?['grade'],
      gender: data?['gender']);
}
```

All fields are null due to some reason, As it was working fine till yesterday.
I already have the user in the collection with above id.
[image]

Below are the rules for my firestore.

[image]

Update:
I tried passing other users ids, they are working fine. Only this user has the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was an some mismatch in the firestore field and datatype maintained in the Model class. Which was creating discrepencies. After matching both, it is working now.